# while put padding in selectbox and use font-family segoe it cuts the text only in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

Hello guys. I have a problem using `font-family:segoe`. I have a `select dropdown` and in this `select` while I apply `padding` in `css` it cuts the text from bottom side see below images

**this is in Mozilla:**

[image: Mozilla]

**this is looking in Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

You can see the difference in both images how can i fix this please help me 
and check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/GqQdU/

**or**
check this code:

**HTML**

```
<select name="select" id="select" class="selinpt">
    <option value="Promotional/Marketing">Promotional/Marketing</option>
    <option value="Tips and Alert">Tips and Alert</option>
    <option value="Information to registered users">Information to registered users</option>
    <option value="Varification process">Verification process</option>
    <option value="Important notice">Important notice</option>
    <option value="API Integration">API Integration</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.selinpt {
    color: #858585;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 404px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
body, input, textarea, select {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe UI Web Regular","Segoe UI Symbol","Helvetica Neue","BBAlpha Sans","S60 Sans",Arial,"sans-serif";
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Please help me. I am stuck in this any kind of help would be appreciated thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
.selinpt {
    color: #858585;
    height: 30px;
    /*padding: 5px 10px;*/
    margin:5px 10px;
    width: 404px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Change the padding to margin, as above, tested in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Scott W can you explain me how margin is works fine rather then padding? as i know margin is taking position outside of an element